# Where can I ask about configuring Eclipse for VB6?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a VB6 project that I want to view/edit (not not build, but maybe in future) in the Eclipse IDE. I am not sure where I can ask this questions? - SO or super user? (or other?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be on topic on SO, given that it's a tool designed to be used by programmers.  It might also be on topic on SU, but you're likely to get better help on SO.